# What software alternatives support streaming via AirPlay?

Tags: software-recommendation, appletv, streaming, airplay

The Apple TV arrived! I'm slightly bummed that I can only stream from iTunes, and therefore only use formats that iTunes supports. I haven't found a single other video player that supports AirPlay, though to be fair, AirPlay has only really been around since the new Apple TVs started arriving.

**What other software supports streaming audio and video to AirPlay devices?** If none, is AirPlay one of those closed Apple standards or have other projects pledged to support it?

Comment: fyi I can stream from my Android phone to my apple tv (3rd gen) using iMediaShare app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To date, there are no 3rd party software implementations of AirPlay. The spec itself is fully patented (though most of these patents relate to the hardware aspects of the system) and is essentially a proprietary standard unique to Apple (though several hardware vendors have announced hardware that will use the standard - XtremeMac, Denon). The current analysis of the protocol itself seems to indicate that it is a further evolution of the previous AirTunes protocol (which itself was built on top of Bonjour), so you are likely to see software implementations appear after developers have had more time to experiment with the protocol.

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Any links to places where there's discussion of the protocol analysis?

Comment: There's been some discussion ovef at the Apple support forums (here moat notably: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2599045&tstart=0), but I haven't seen any technical discussion of the protocol by people who have it in hand. Likely to change over the next week as people start playing with their AppleTVs a bit more.

Comment: For my money, I'd follow Mac geek goddess, Erica Sadun who is actively working on getting into the innards (from a software perspective) and usually posts at TUAW (such as this recent post: http://www.tuaw.com/2010/10/01/apple-tv-hacking-update-airtunes-bonjour-services-dfu-mode/).

Comment: Have you seen http://ericasadun.com/ftp/AirPlay/?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/).

Comment: It seems like Airfoil only supports old-style audio streaming via the technology that has existed in the Airport Express. It definitely seems like they would want to upgrade it for video, but it doesn't look like they have yet.

Comment: Speaking of Airfoil, though ... I had been thinking of picking up an old Airport Express to plug into my soundbar via optical and stream stuff via iTunes & Airfoil.  But with AirPlay taking off, maybe this doesn't make sense?

Comment: They say they support the new Apple TV 2.

Answer (score 2):

AirPlay is effectively a rebranding of AirTunes and adds video/photo streaming. The AirTunes protocol, called RAOP (really just RTSP w/ encryption) remains mostly unchanged. Video streaming is a different animal. My understanding is that its basically push DAAP.

**3rd-Party Software**
*Audio-Only*
Airfoil
[audio|acacia](http://www.plethra.com)

*Video+Audio*
[AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com)
For the sake of brevity and time, this list is non-exhaustive and I've only listed commercial software. I've personally noticed that some of the software products touting AirPlay/AirTunes support don't follow the protocols exactly and results vary. I guess you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Beamer](https://beamer-app.com/). It's a little pricey ($20), but it was money well spent, for me! It functions very similarly to the ChromeCast, in that you're not actually "mirroring" the content from your computer screen, but rather, casting it wirelessly to the Apple TV. It supports every major file format, to date, as well. What I like most about it, is that one can still thumb around on their computer, while streaming their shows and/or movies. That's always been a huge downfall of the AirPlay function, for me... I am not a fan of mirroring, at all!! Anyhow, hope that helps anyone who may have stumbled across this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old question but it may help others.
You can try [AirMyPC](http://www.airmypc.com) software. It can wirelessly AirPlay Mirror your Windows computer to your AppleTV.